# using path function and a slug from a different function

Tags: python, django

So I have an url like "/dramaName" with

```
path('<slug>', views.seasons, name='seasons'),
```

On top of this I want to have "/dramaName/s1e1" but the problem is I'm not sure how to bring the slug dramaName to the new url.
in views.py

```
#the below method allows me to create a page with the seasons of the specific drama. 
def seasons(request, slug):
    seasons = Season.objects.filter(drama__name=slug)
```

now as for the contents I want it to be like drama/s1e1 but to do that I need to borrow slug from the above view for the drama part. I'm just not sure how to do that

```
def contents(request, slug):
    content = Content.objects.filter(
```

do I put two slug for the arguments? how do I filter twice?

```
#path('<slug:>/<slug>', views.contents, name='contents'),
```

can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can name arguments, something like:

**In urls:**

```
path('<slug:slug1>/<slug:slug2>', my_view.test)
```

**In views:**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def test(request, slug1, slug2):
    return HttpResponse(slug1 + '   '+  slug2)
```

Call url like `your_domain/howIMeetYourMother/S01E01`

**Output is like:**

[image]